# Custom jQuery scroll

Tags: theming

I'm new to drupal 7 and I'm having issues getting the smooth div scroll to work. What I'm going for is [this](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html)! I also need it to be on every page of the site.

I downloaded the Zip file which is actually for [this](http://smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo)! I figured I'll alter the **js** and **css files** later. I placed in both sites/all/libraries and sites/all/modules. I copied the jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min file to /modules folder.

I then pasted this code to my template.php :

```
function best_responsive_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

//  if we are at frontpage, add some jquery code to do the animation
   if ($vars['is_front']) {
      drupal_add_js('sites/all/modules/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min');
      drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/SmoothdivScroll/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js');
      drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/SmoothdivScroll/css/smoothDivScroll.css');
       $vars['script'] = drupal_get_js();
       $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
   }
}
```

But that didn't do the trick.

What could be the issue here, or perhaps there is an another way to achieving this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your function called ?
put a `drupal_set_message('hello');` in it to see.

remove these to lines, they're not needed

```
$vars['script'] = drupal_get_js();
$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
```

then - you need to add some custom JS, where you tell which of your div should be modified:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { $("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({ 
    autoScrollingMode: "always", 
    autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight", 
    autoScrollingStep: 1, 
    autoScrollingInterval: 25 
});

// Logo parade event handlers
$("#logoParade").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
}).bind("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
}); });', 'inline')
```

is this div already setup ?

else - add it in page.tpl.php or whereever you like to ..

Comment: Where do I need to paste the custom js?

Comment: do that in your best_responsive_preprocess_page function

Comment: I'm getting errors when pasting the custom js after the best_responsive_preprocess_page function. Here is a [link](https://github.com/ISynesthesiaI/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/Code)! to the code.

Comment: how does your HTML look like ? / what error's do you get ?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\Users\Martin\Sites\acquia-drupal\sites\all\themes\best_responsive\template.php on line 96" I added the HTML code to the previous link. Do you need to see the full HTML before I edited the template.php file?

Comment: i meant the HTML code of the site without error, containing the id="logoparade" div, or whatever. your error is here `autoScrollingInterval: 25 
});`, change to `autoScrollingInterval: 25 
});');` - also you call `drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { $("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll` outside of the preprocess funtion, move it in there ..